# HTML Form and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite, get

OK, I have been trying to figure this out for a while. I just recently figured out how to use apache's mod_rewrite rules. I have a search script set up on my website and it uses GET. I have a html form with the GET method. The problem is when I submit the form my url comes out like this: http://localhost/search/?search=name&term=user when it should be this: http://localhost/search/name/user

Is there a way to make the url like the second? I am using php.

Here is my htaccess file as well:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member/?([^/\.]+)?/?$ member.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^games/?([^/\.]+)?/([^/\.]+)?/?$ games.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/?([^/\.]+)?/([^/\.]+)?/?$ search.php?search=$1&term=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Thanks,
Legobear154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mod_rewrite. You need to use JavaScript.

Create an *[onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)* event handler for your form. And in the javascript function modify the form URL according to the form data.

Comment: So, I can't just do a mod_rewrite to modify the query string? I was reading through the apache docs and found this: Modifying the Query String

By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

Comment: Mod_reqrite starts to work after a request have been made. It can not change URL at client side. Because you haven't created the URL , let alone a request.

Comment: ok, how would I go about modifying the form URL in javascript? I know some javascript, but not a lot.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on http://www.w3schools.com/js/ for you. Also you need to see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_form.asp I.e. form object

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/ member.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ games.php?page=$1&p=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /search.php?search=$1&term=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Hope it helps.